# javascript conditions applied on independant objects

Tags: javascript, loops, conditional-statements

I'm going crazy for i do not understand the behavior of my loop!
here a sample of a json I read :

```
[{"type":"robot","town":"NANTES","region":"Ouest","performances":[{"date":YYYY-MM-DD","value":100},{...}],"availability":[{"date":"YYY-MM-DD","value":100},{...}]},{"type":"robot","town":"RENNES","region":"Ouest","performances":[{"date":YYYY-MM-DD","value":100},{...}],"availability":[{"date":"YYY-MM-DD","value":100},{...}]}
```

I create 2 objects :

```
REGIONS = {},TOWNS= {};
```

here is the function the moment i recieve the object:

```
function getRobotsDatas(robotList) {
    for (var i = 0; i < robotList.length; i++) {
        var robot = robotList[i];
// working on TOWNS object
//I check if the "town" object of TOWNS object already exist
        if (TOWNS[robot.town] === undefined) { 
// if not, i create it
            TOWNS[robot.town] = {}; 
//then i push performances datas of my robot in my TOWNS.town object
            TOWNS[robot.town].performances = robot.performances; 
// the same for availability datas
            TOWNS[robot.town].availability= robot.availability; 
        } 

// then I work nearly the same way on REGIONS object.
//i check if the "region" object exist in REGIONS object. If not, i create it and add the perf+availability datas of the robot.
        if (REGIONS[robot.region] === undefined) { 
            REGIONS[robot.region] = {};
            REGIONS[robot.region].performances = robot.performances;
            REGIONS[robot.region].availability= robot.availability;
        } 
// If the REGIONS.region already exist, i just want to add the datas of performances and availability in the already existing arrays of REGIONS.region (performances[] and availabilities[])
        else {
            for (var j = 0; j < robot.performances.length; j++) {
                REGIONS[robot.region].performances.push(robot.performances[j]);
            }
            for (var k = 0; k < robot.availability.length; k++) {
                REGIONS[robot.region].availability.push(robot.availability[k]);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the condition for an already existing "REGIONS.region" is also applied on TOWNS. It adds values of performances and availabilities in the TOWNS objects of the robots which have the same value of the "region" attribut.
for example, in the sample i gave at the beginning, i'll find availabilities and perf datas in a new object : REGIONS.Ouest {performances:[...], availability:[...]}, but i will also find NANTES' perf an availibilities datas in RENNES' perf and availabilities arrays... and THAT, i don't want!

What's wrong with my condition / loop!???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem of variable Reference. try this simple change **JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(xxx))**

```
function getRobotsDatas(robotList) {
    for (var i = 0; i < robotList.length; i++) {
        var robot = robotList[i];
        if (TOWNS[robot.town] === undefined) { 
            TOWNS[robot.town] = {}; 
            TOWNS[robot.town].performances = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(robot.performances)); 
            TOWNS[robot.town].disponibilite = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(robot.availability)); 
        } 
        if (REGIONS[robot.region] === undefined) { 
            REGIONS[robot.region] = {};
            REGIONS[robot.region].performances = robot.performances;
            REGIONS[robot.region].availability= robot.availability;
        } 
        else {
            for (var j = 0; j < robot.performances.length; j++) {
                REGIONS[robot.region].performances.push(robot.performances[j]);
            }
            for (var k = 0; k < robot.availability.length; k++) {
                REGIONS[robot.region].availability.push(robot.availability[k]);
            }
        }


   }
}
```

*JS is funny.... :)*

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! that is exactly what I was looking for without being able to explain it :D

Comment: great @CoStiC :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code refers to 'town' but your incoming JSON has 'ville' instead.
I appreciate that this won't fix the problem, but the example should at least be correct.

The incoming JSON has two sub-objects. For each one, you test for presence in your Towns and Regions data structures. If they don't each have a matching entry, you are creating one, and then adding entries in the two further sub-objects (performances and availability).

If you don't want this in both cases, you need to test the incoming JSON appropriately.

Comment: You’re right, I forgot to translate it... but this is not the problem think that « ville » is « town » :)

Comment: i corrected my example when i answered the first time.

Comment: i said you were right and corrected my example when i answered the first time. I create each objects towns and regions from robot.region and robot.town. i do want that. And I also want to add values of all towns in a same region to the regions object. what i don t want is adding values from town2 to town1 even if they are from the same region.